# DrRacket - numerical equivalents of letters

Tags: racket

I'm writing a function that replaces every letter by the one found exactly 13 spaces later around the alphabetical circle, and leave non-letter characters unchanged. For letters A-N and a-n, I only have to add 13 to the corresponding integer and then convert it to character. This is where it confuses me - For letters N-Z and n-z, the corresponding integer after decoding should be subtracted by 13, and I don't know how to write the question-expressions. I've tried using char<=? and char>=? but there was error.

```
(define (rot-13 msg)
  (list->string (list-rot-13 (string->list msg))))

(define (list-rot-13 loc)
  (cond
    [(empty? loc) empty]
    [else
     (cons (convert-char (first loc)) (list-rot-13 (rest loc)))]))

(define (convert-char c)
  (cond
    [... (integer->char (- (char->integer c) 13))]
    [... (integer->char (+ (char->integer c) 13))]
    [else c])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `char-ci>=?`. Eg.

```
(char-ci>=? #\l #\n) ; ==> #f
(char-ci>=? #\n #\n) ; ==> #t
(char-ci>=? #\p #\n) ; ==> #t
```

Now `char>=?` is the same as `>=` for numbers, and `(char>=? #\A #\b) ; ==> #t`. `ci` stands for case insensitive so `(char>=? #\A #\b) ; ==> #f`.

PS: I think you can do with only one predicate and it would work with just `if`. Either it is equal or larger than `#\n`or it isn't. You can also do the `if` inside the math operation by always adding `(integer->char (+ (char->integer c) (if (char-ci>=? ...) -13 13))`